# METADATA$ROW_ID outside a stream?

Tags: stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(1) In snowflake, is there a way to access METADATA$ROW_ID outside of a snowflake table stream?

(2) Am I correct in thinking that this ROW_ID is actually necessary to process UPDATEs correctly? (The docs make it seem rather optional.)

Somewhat related,

(3) When a stream is exported and multiple files get created, is there any guarantee that each DELETE-INSERT pair will end up in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, you'd need to store it in your downstream tables in order to use it, later.

2) Necessary only if you don't have a natural key in your data to use to UPDATE/MERGE on.

3) No, there isn't a way to guarantee what records get into which files on an COPY INTO location statement.  The only option here is to it to SINGLE_FILE, which might not be an option and is a slower process.